# Pyspark mapping regex

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe, with text column.

1. I wanted to map the values which with a regex expression.

```
    df = df.withColumn('mapped_col', regexp_replace('mapped_col', '.*-RH', 'RH'))
    df = df.withColumn('mapped_col', regexp_replace('mapped_col', '.*-FI, 'FI'))
```

2. Plus I wanted to map specifics values according to a dictionnary, I did the following (mapper is from create_map()):

```
     df = df.withColumn("mapped_col",mapper.getItem(F.col("action")))
```

3. Finaly the values which has not been mapped by the dictionnary or the regex expression, will be set null. I do not know how to do this part in accordance to the two others.

Is it possible to have like a dictionnary of regex expression so I can regroup the two 'functions'?
{".*-RH": "RH", ".*FI" : "FI"}

### Original Output Example

```
+-----------------------------+
|message                      |
+-----------------------------+
|GDF2009                      | 
|GDF2014                      |
|ADS-set                      |
|ADS-set                      |
|XSQXQXQSDZADAA5454546a45a4-FI|
|dadaccpjpifjpsjfefspolamml-FI|
|dqdazdaapijiejoajojp565656-RH|
|kijipiadoa
+-----------------------------+
```

### Expected Output Example

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|message                      |status|
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|GDF2009                      | GDF
|GDF2014                      | GDF
|ADS/set                      | ADS
|ADS-set                      | ADS 
|XSQXQXQSDZADAA5454546a45a4-FI| FI
|dadaccpjpifjpsjfefspolamml-FI| FI
|dqdazdaapijiejoajojp565656-RH| RH
|kijipiadoa                   | null or ??
```

So first 4th line are mapped with a dict, and the other are mapped using regex. Unmapped are null or ??
Thank you,

Comment: Could you add input and expected output dataframe?

Comment: I have edited my post, I hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `contains` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["GDF2009", "GDF2014", "ADS-set", "ADS-set", "XSQXQXQSDZADAA5454546a45a4-FI", "dadaccpjpifjpsjfefspolamml-FI",
     "dqdazdaapijiejoajojp565656-RH", "kijipiadoa"], StringType()).toDF("message")
df.show()

names = ("GDF", "ADS", "FI", "RH")

def c(col, names):
    return [f.when(f.col(col).contains(i), i).otherwise("") for i in names]

df.select("message", f.concat_ws("", f.array_remove(f.array(*c("message", names)), "")).alias("status")).show()
```

output:

```
+--------------------+
|             message|
+--------------------+
|             GDF2009|
|             GDF2014|
|             ADS-set|
|             ADS-set|
|XSQXQXQSDZADAA545...|
|dadaccpjpifjpsjfe...|
|dqdazdaapijiejoaj...|
|          kijipiadoa|
+--------------------+

+--------------------+------+
|             message|status|
+--------------------+------+
|             GDF2009|   GDF|
|             GDF2014|   GDF|
|             ADS-set|   ADS|
|             ADS-set|   ADS|
|XSQXQXQSDZADAA545...|    FI|
|dadaccpjpifjpsjfe...|    FI|
|dqdazdaapijiejoaj...|    RH|
|          kijipiadoa|      |
+--------------------+------+
```